# How can I make a command that accepts an information, more in the post

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

A command that does something like this, thanks to anyone who helps me

Example:

```
user: !say Hello

Bot: Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends *how* you want to accept that information.  Do you only want to accept [a single word](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#positional), but ignore extra words?

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, word):
    await ctx.send(word)
```

Would you like to accept [any number of inputs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#variable), but treat them separately?

```
@bot.command()
async def longest(ctx, *words):
    await ctx.send(max(words, key=len))
```

Or would you like to [process the rest of the message as a single string](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments), potentially comprised of many words?

```
@bot.command()
async def echo(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make the bot repeat the author's message, and delete the original, try using this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def say(ctx, *args):
    mesg = ''.join(args)
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    return await bot.say(mesg)
```